# Put a "," sign on the number

Tags: c#, database, winforms

i wanna ask. How do i put "," sign on the number whenever the number length is more than 3, then add 1 "," sign.

for example:
I have a number "100000000", and i want computer display it as "100.000.000,00", how do i do that?

Here is the image:
[image]

In picture above, shown that the SubTotal is "10000", i want computer display it as "10.000,00" and the Total beside SubTotal is "10000000", i want computer display it as "10.000.000,00".

My question is: how do i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is the form using some sort of grid control or a bunch in individual controls arranged together?

Comment: Have a look at [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Dhaval: yes correct, this is written in c#

Comment: @SameerSingh .. i am going to send the same comment that is why asked is it in C#?

Comment: @DStanley: no, it's not

Comment: @Fuhans Sameer already answered the question

Comment: @Dhaval the question is tagged C# ...

Comment: I think you need a "custom format specifier" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh

Comment: @Fuhans That was an either/or not a yes/no question.  If you are not using either of those please explain how your controls get their values.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
amount.ToString("N");
```

Comment: In many countries in Europe, the dot is used as thousands separator and the comma as decimal "point", so his request is valid.

Comment: To both: You may be right. I didn't think of different countries. Thanks for pointing it. I am removing the last line of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is worked. And, it is right what @BartFriederichs said, in my country, used "," as decimal point

Comment: @Fuhans: Great! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it depends on the control(s) you are using.  If you're using plain text boxes you can just set the format when setting the `Text` value:

```
txtbox1.Text = total.ToString("N2");  // numeric with separators and 2 decimal places
```

Other third-party controls let you choose the format with a property such as `NumberFormat`.  Grid controls usually set the format on a column rather than an individual cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it programmatically:

```
int myNumber = 10000000;
string output = String.Format("{0:n2}", myNumber);
```

or

```
int myNumber = 10000000;
string output = myNumber.ToString("n2");
```

The number after `n` is the number of decimal places (which can be 0 if you want).

Or you might need to set a format string of a user control to `"n2"` (without quotes) depending on how you are displaying the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) on MSDN.

You should use the [numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString) to achieve what you want:

```
number.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```